# Basic C Pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm a beginner in C and have been trying to figure out what has gone wrong with my code code for the past hour or two. I have been following through K&Rs book and I keep looking through it but still do not understand my logic mistake.

```
while (*argv>0){
    while (**argv>0){
        printf("%c\n",**argv);
        **argv++;
    }
    argv++;
}
```

Task:Print out all the arguments being fed to my program using argv.

To my understanding, argv is a pointer to an array that contains further pointers to arrays of character pointers. So, I said that while *argv>0 or while the first array still has elements, we should follow the pointers from the first array to the next array. Then we should print out all the elements in the next array.

Comment: Thinking in terms of patterns is very helpful. Notice that you have `*argv` and `argv++` in the outer loop, but `**argv` and `**argv++` in the inner loop; one of those must be wrong ... in fact, `**argv++` is wrong and should be `*argv++`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Too many * in this line:

```
**argv++;
```

It should be like this:

```
*argv++;
```

Plus additional braces, because the `++` operation has higher priority:

```
(*argv)++;
```

And it will work.

Comment: Isn't it dangerous to leave the while statement checking that argv>0?  You don't know whats in the memory after argv, or is there some standard that argv is always followed by 0's? 
Edit: I just read below that there is guarantee that argv[argc] is a null pointer... so nevermind.

Comment: @AdamCadien I believe it's still dangerous to do `argv > 0` (instead of `argv != 0`), as I can't find any guarantee that a null pointer constant must compare less that other pointers.

Comment: @Adam Cadien: yes, the standard defines that the element `argv[argc]` is always a null pointer. However, KennyTM's criticism still applies.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest you don't confuse yourself by using pointer dereferencing the way you do when the subscript notation (`[]`) allows you to do the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; argv[i]; i++)
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

This will also print `argv[0]`, which is the name/path of the program.

Now what does my code do? `for(i = 0; argv[i]; i++)` counts up `i` from `0` to the element when `argv[i]` resolves to false (i.e. `0` aka `NULL`), that is the last element of the `argv` array. And then for every element in the array it uses the `%s` format specifier of `printf` to print it. You could also pass the `argv[i]` as the first and only parameter to `printf`, but that is usually frowned upon as it opens the door for certain string formatting attacks.

Comment: passing the string as the only argument wont even produce correct results a lot of the time. e.g. the string "C:\never" will result in "C:" + newline + "ever".

Comment: @chacham15: I was more hinting at security-relevant attacks, but that's true, too.

Comment: +1 for sticking to the obscure guarantee that `argv[argc]` will be a null pointer.

Comment: chacham15's point is that it isn't just frowned up, it's downright wrong ... if the first argument contains `%` characters, the program is likely to crash. `puts(argv[i])` does what you want.

Answer (score 6):

`argv` is of type `char *argv[]` i.e. a pointer to an array of strings (`char*`'s). `argv++` moves to the next string in the array.

Usually this function would be written as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < argc; i++){ //loop from 0 to argc (argument count)
      printf("%s ", argv[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: cdecl is a nice resource to understand C's typing: [http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char+*argv%5B%5D](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char+*argv%5B%5D)

Comment: You might want to explicitly mention: `argc` contains the number of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

this will work::

```
while(argc--)//can't use *argv here, because *argv would be the  address of the 
              // element which argv is pointing to, just by knowing the address u can't say whether it still has elements or not
{
    while( **argv )
    {
        printf("%c", **argv);
        (*argv)++;  //by using **argv++, you are actually moving argv to next array, not to the next character of current array 
    }
    argv++;
    printf("\n");//move your \n to here, else you will end up printing every character in a new line
}
```